# Detecting and installing wifi adapter

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I am new to this, so please help me out. I just brought a wifi adapter to plug into my pi and use it wirelessly connect to router. But, I am not sure it supports, well I am using headless pi, and when using **dmesg** it gives out following output related to wlan

```
new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
New USB device strings:Mfr=1,Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Manufacturer: MediaTek
SerialNumber: 1.0
```

Well, everything looks fine, but I am not able to set it up, Since new version of raspbean made all tutorials obsolete(I've tried them, It doesn't work).
And, My Pi's Desktop(Which i access through vnc server) also not shows any wifi config utility. I don't how to set it up. Please guide my thoroughly cause I am absolute novice and let me get this straight.

**How do i set up that Wireless Adapter.!! step by step**

PS
These tutorials didn't worked: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md
http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/

No Network icon on upper right corner of raspberry pi's desktop.

Using Pi headless, Pi is connected to the router via ethernet and my pc is connected to router via wifi, and i am sshing into it using putty

Comment: It is quite possible that you're using a wifi adapter which is not supported by raspbian by default. You may have to install drivers explicitly to make it work. Can you give us out put of `lsusb` command ? It will help us understand which wifi adapter you're using. Also, a link of one that you're using can help as well.

Comment: yeah this is the device i am using 
http://imgur.com/FtkBmb7
in comments, the seller do actually mentions that it works with pi
and here's the lsusb
http://imgur.com/9EIyaIn
the last one with the ralink tech. is the device i think.

Answer (score 0):

The 7601 has long caused problems on the Raspberry Pi, requiring special driver builds.

Those days seem to be coming to an end.

The latest kernels (and Raspbian) have a suitable driver but you need to download some firmware.

```
sudo wget https://github.com/porjo/mt7601/raw/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin -O /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

See this Raspberry Pi org [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=813770#p813770) for details.

Once you have done that, and rebooted, the system should see your dongle.  You can then follow one of the generic wifi tutorials if it is not immediately usable.